# Is there a way that i can download files from different URL's based on user input?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

There are two releases 
1. Dev available at https://example.com/foo/new-package.txt 
2. GA available at https://example.com/bar/new-package.txt
I want the user to enter his choice of Dev or GA and based on that need to download the files, in the shell script is there a better way to do it?

There is a file which has environment variables that I'm sourcing inside another script.

env_var.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter your release"
export release=''   #either Dev or GA
```

This file will be sourced from another script as

download.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

. ./env_var.sh    #sourcing a environment var file

wget https://<Dev or GA URL>/new-package.txt
```

My main problem is how to set the wget URL based on the release set in env_var file.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `read` to get the user input?

```
read -p 'Selection: ' choice
```

You could then pass `${choice}` to a function that has case statements for the urls:

```
get_url() {
    case $1 in
        'dev' ) wget https://example.com/foo/new-package.txt ;;
        'ga' ) wget https://example.com/bar/new-package.txt ;;
        \? ) echo "Invalid choice" ;;
    esac
}
```

For more information on `read`, a good reference is [TLDP's guide on user input](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html).

Edit: To source a config file, run the command `source ${PATH_TO_FILE}`. You would then be able to pass the variable to the `get_url()` function for the same result.

Comment: Thanks, I just did not want the user to give any input at the terminal, but this idea got me triggered. Just to clarify, I want the user input -- but not at the terminal , I was looking for input of release in the env_var.sh file and then execute it from main script.

Comment: @DirectedSoul The function I posted earlier could still be used the same way after you source the file; I have modified my response to include how to source a file for its functions/values.

Comment: Thanks @ThatsWhatSheCoded

Comment: You're very welcome, @DirectedSoul! Please mark as solved if your initial post has been resolved.